# MongoDB server failed after system reboot

Tags: server, 20.04, reboot, mongodb

I installed MongoDB using `sudo apt install mongo-org` and followed the instruction to start and everything worked but then when I reboot the system, the MongoDB server failed

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented >database 
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor prese> 
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-02-15 09:14:37 IST; 2min> 
    Process: 836 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (c> 
   Main PID: 836 (code=exited, status=48)
Feb 15 09:14:05 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free docume>
Feb 15 09:14:37 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=e>
Feb 15 09:14:37 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-co>
```

I tried changing the permissions of lib/MongoDB and log/mongodb, setting the ulimit of open files to 64000, but nothing worked for me.

What I do till now to do my work is to reinstall MongoDB every time on reboot.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ask Ubuntu... there is no package called [mongo-org](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mongo-org&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in the standard Ubuntu repositories. What did you install there?. Also, the error messages are missing: post the output for `journalctl -e | tee`

Comment: Assuming that the exit code will be the same as the status (48), then that indicates that MongoDB couldn't start because something else was using its port. Run `lsof -i | grep 27017` and see if there is something else — perhaps another instance of MongoDB — appears. If so, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my problem get resolved by the following steps

1. `sudo apt --purge autoremove mongo-org*`
2. `sudo apt install mongodb`
3. `sudo service mongodb start`
4. `sudo service mongodb status`

At this point it gives an error `"couldn't open /etc/mongod.conf, No such file in directory"`

On checking /etc I saw that it contains `mongodb.conf` not `mongod.conf`, So I edited `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service` and changed mongod.conf to mongodb.conf

After that, I did steps 3 and 4 and everything was working.